# Node.js backend to recieve javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I want to use javascript fetch to post data to Node.js backend. I use fetch on the javascript side in angular 2 functions.

In my front end I have button to save data to array:

```
<input #data /><button (click)="addGoal(data.value)">Add</button>
<ul><li *ngFor="let goal of goals">{{goal}}</li></ul>

<br/><button (click)="saveData()">Save</button>
```

Angular 2 side i add data into array goals and call angular 2 function addGoal from the front end:

```
  export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Goals';
  goals = [];

  addGoal(goal:string) {
    this.goals.push(goal);

  }
  saveData() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/", {
      method: "POST",
      mode:"no-cors",
      body: {goals: this.goals},
    });
  }
}
```

I want to get data to backend to later save it to the database.
Node.js side:

```
var data = {};
app.post('/',function (req,res) {
  data = req.body;
})
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

  res.send(data);
})
```

However, this is not a correct solution. Can you help me?

**edit:** Body.fetch functions(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body) not seem to work.

Comment: What error makes you think this isn't working?

Comment: I can't view req.body

Comment: Please consider editing your question to provide the full details of both requests.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using express, you need to `use` the [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware. If you are dealing with html5 `FormData`/multiplart formdata, you need [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).